# If $f(0)=g(0)=0$, $f'(x)>g'(x)$, is it guaranteed that $f^{-1}{'}(x)<g^{-1}{'}(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Given two monotonically increasing convex functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, suppose that $f(0)=g(0)=0$, $f'(x)>g'(x)$, and $f^{-1}{'}(x), g^{-1}{'}(x)$ are the inverse functions of $f, g$, respectively. Is it guaranteed that $f^{-1}{'}(x)<g^{-1}{'}(x)$? If yes, how to prove it?

Take $f(x)=x^3, g(x)=x^2$ for example, it is easy to prove that $f^{-1}{'}(x)<g^{-1}{'}(x)$. How to prove or disprove this for general functions $f, g$ satisfying above conditions?

Comment: $g(x) = 0~~~~~~$

Comment: I have added conditions to $f$ and $g$, which are confined to monotonically increasing convex functions.

Comment: Hint: what is the formula for $f^{-1'}(x)$ with respect to $f(x)$?

Comment: Hi @Salcio, in my problem, if we don't know the formula of $f$, can we prove that statement?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to suggest that you have to know the formula for $f$. Rather that $f^{-1'}(x)=\frac{1}{f^{'}(x)}$

Comment: It's not that simple, @Salcio. $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)$ evaluated at $x=x_0$ is $\frac{1}{df/dx}$ evaluated at $f^{-1}(x_0)$. So you are comparing $\frac{1}{df/dx}$ evaluated at $f^{-1}(x_0)$ with $\frac{1}{dg/dx}$ evaluated at $g^{-1}(x_0)$, and you can't directly use the fact that $f'>g'$, because you are evaluating them at different points.

Comment: @TonyK, Yes. I know that $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=1$. I can't use this relation directly. Because, when comparing $f^{-1}{'}(t)$ and  $g^{-1}{'}(t)$, we are comparing $\frac{1}{f'(x_1)}$ and $\frac{1}{g'(x_2)}$ such that $f(x_1)=g(x_2)=t$.

Comment: I don't think it's true. I am working on a counterexample.

Comment: @Salcio, would you post your proof in detail, please?

Comment: @TonyK, it is false. Here is a counterexample. Let $I(a<x<b)$ be the indication function taking $1$ when $a<x<b$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $g(x)=0.5x\times I(0<x<2)+(1.5x-2)\times I(x\geq 2)$, and $f(x)=x\times I(0<x<2)+(2x-4)\times I(x\geq 2)$. Then $f^{-1}{'}(1.5)=1$, $g^{-1}{'}(1.5)=1.5$

Comment: Sorry to everybody for messing it up ... it looked so simple and natural ( $f$ grows faster than $g$ so $g^{-1}$ grows faster than $f^{-1}$ so derivative of $g^{-1}$ should be bigger than derivative of $f^{-1}$). Here is another counterexample: $f(x)=x^{2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{3}$. One checks that at 1 derivatives do not satisfy the conclusions.

Comment: @Salcio, yes. I was confused too. So I post this question. In fact, what I really need is here. [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996676/how-to-prove-this-function-is-decreasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996676/how-to-prove-this-function-is-decreasing). I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @TonyK, what I really need is here [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996676/how-to-prove-this-function-is-decreasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996676/how-to-prove-this-function-is-decreasing). I don't know how to prove it.